# Is there a way I can use the 'if' function to print out a string depending on the first letter of the original input string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, indexing

Is there a way I can use an if function to determine if the first letter of a string is a vowel and if not, then print something else?

I've done quite a bit of research and the answers I found were too far advanced for me to understand. This is a small challenge I've handed myself that is based off of CodeAcademy's 'Pyg Latin' Translator

```
translate = input("Translate: ")
cons = "ay"
vowel = "way"
if len(translate) > 0:
    switch = str(translate[0])
    if str(translate[0]) != "a, e, i, o, u":
        new_word = str(translate) + str(switch) + str(cons)
        print (new_word.lower())

else:
    new_word = str(translate) + str(vowel)
    print (new_word.lower())

else:
    print("Please type something")
```

The job is to add "Way" or "Ay" depending on whether 'translate' begins with a vowel.
I feel as though i'm skipping over something completely obvious but I can't figure it out. 
The program is pretty much ignoring line 6, 
Jordan comes out as Jordanjay
Andrew comes out as Andrewaay

Comment: Imagine it *is* a vowel, what do you think `"a" == "a, e, i, o, u"` would evaluate to?

Comment: a == a would mean true, right? My problem is i'm trying to tell it that if it's not true, then use 'this' and if it is true use 'that'

Comment: I'd suggest you try it out, I doubt it's the answer you expect.

Comment: if translate[0].lower() not in "a, e, i, o, u":

Comment: I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

in line :

```
if str(translate[0]) != "a, e, i, o, u":
```

you are taking first letter of translate (translate[0])

for example you have translate = 'example', the first letter is 'e'

you are comparing(!= which mean DIFFEREN) 'e' with another string "a, e, i, o, u", your first letter will alvays be different than string "a, e, i, o, u", you need to check if your first leter is not in that string, you can use:

```
if str(translate[0]) not in "a, e, i, o, u":
```

or you can check if your letter is not in the list:

```
if str(translate[0]) not in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
```

How do I check if something is (not) in a list in Python?
The cheapest and most readable solution is using the in operator (or in your specific case, not in). As mentioned in the documentation,

> The operators **in** and **not in** test for membership. **x in s** evaluates to 
>   True if x is a member of s, and False otherwise. **x not in s** returns
>   the negation of x in s.

Additionally,

> The operator **not in** is defined to have the inverse true value of **in**.

y not in x is logically the same as not y in x.

Here are a few examples:

```
'a' in [1, 2, 3]
# False

'c' in ['a', 'b', 'c']
# True

'a' not in [1, 2, 3]
# True

'c' not in ['a', 'b', 'c']
# False
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your answer! This worked wonders and gave me a little bit more understand of the language overall!